# python inconsistency in Pandas arithmetic

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas, anaconda

I ran the follwing piece of code on different machines (linux and windows, 32/64 bits) and got differnet results (sometimes all results are `inf` or `-inf`, sometimes the first is `inf` and the rest are numbers, sometimes the first is `NaN` and the rest are numbers.
Can someone explain?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[0.,  -5.5,  -5.6,   -6.5,   -3.5,  -4.5, -4.5], "B":[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 30]})
print df.A/df.B
```

Additional info

when I used:  `... "B":[0., ...` instead of `... "B":[0, ...` it always gives numbers.

```
Sample results:
In [15]: print df.A/df.B
0    inf
1   -inf
2   -inf
3   -inf
4   -inf
5   -inf
6   -inf
dtype: float64

In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,  -5.5,  -5.6,   -6.5,   -3.5,  -4.5, -4.5], "B":[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 30]})

In [17]: print df.A/df.B
0    inf
1   -inf
2   -inf
3   -inf
4   -inf
5   -inf
6   -inf
dtype: float64

In [18]: print df.B/df.A
0         NaN
1   -0.181818
2   -0.178571
3   -0.153846
4   -0.285714
5   -0.444444
6   -6.666667
dtype: float64

In [19]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[0.,  -5.5,  -5.6,   -6.5,   -3.5,  -4.5, -4.5], "B":[0., 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 30]})

In [20]: print df.A/df.B
0     NaN
1   -5.50
2   -5.60
3   -6.50
4   -3.50
5   -2.25
6   -0.15
dtype: float64

In [21]: print df.B/df.A
0         NaN
1   -0.181818
2   -0.178571
3   -0.153846
4   -0.285714
5   -0.444444
6   -6.666667
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your first two, they calculate correctly: `Out[180]:
0         inf
1   -5.500000
2   -5.600000
3   -6.500000
4   -3.500000
5   -2.250000
6   -0.150000
dtype: float64` can you add the pandas and numpy version

Comment: looks like you have an older version of pandas, can you show version?

Comment: @EdChum: yes - after I posted we (at the office) tried to reproduce on different machines (Win\Linux, 32\64 bits) We got different result and nothing was consistent.

Comment: @Jeff: This is the printout:
Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 10:40:02) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: Pandas versions are (on different machines) 0.13.1\0.14.1.